How to test IObservable with rx.net
I have method like:
public IObservable<int> Move()
{
    byte[] header = { <some data> };

    return _joystickService.JoystickXY()
        .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        .CombineLatest(
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
            (data, _) =>
            {
                byte[] dataToSend = [<some data>];

                return dataToSend;
            }
        )
        .SelectMany(data => Observable
            .Using(
                () => new UdpClient(),
                udpClient => Observable.FromAsync(() => udpClient.SendAsync(data.dataToSend, data.dataToSend.Length, ip, _remotePort))
                    .Catch((Exception ex) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Exception when sending data: {ex.Message}");
                        return Observable.Empty<int>();
                    })
        ));

}

I want to check that after 3 seconds, data from the stream _joystickService.JoystickXY() will pass through the method. I am trying something like this:
// Arrange
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
var joystickData = testScheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, new Tuple<double, double>(100, 200)),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks, new Tuple<double, double>(200, 300)),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks, new Tuple<double, double>(200, 300))
    );

_joystickServiceMock.Setup(x => x.JoystickXY()).Returns(joystickData);

var sut = new UdpDataService(_joystickServiceMock.Object);

// Act
ITestableObserver<int> testableObserver = testScheduler.Start(sut.Move);
testScheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks);


// Assert
testableObserver.Messages.Count.Should().Be(3);

This means that 3 messages (from joystickData) should be received after 3 seconds, but there are 0.

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
